# Python : Problem recreating replace function

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

trying to make a string replace function as a beginner(i don't want to use an existing function , I am just appliying my knowledge)

```
word = input("Enter a string : ")

def Ino_String(word,part):
    # if part is in word s will indicate the position where the starting position of part is in word
    # if not s will stay -1
    s = -1

    i = 0
    j = 0
    count = 0
    while i < len(word):
        if word[i] == part[j]:
            count += 1
            j += 1
            i += 1
        else:
            count = 0
            i = i - j + 1
            j = 0
        if count == len(part):
            s = i - len(part)
            break
    return s

def  First_Replace(word,  part, new_part):
    s = Ino_String(word, part)
    if s != -1 :
        new_word = ""
        for i in range(s):
            new_word += word[i]
        for i in range(0, len(new_part)):
            new_word += new_part[i]
        i = s + len(part)
        while i < len(word):
            new_word += word[i]
    else:
        new_word = "Error: the part you want to replace is not in the string"
    return new_word

print(str(Ino_String(word,"hy")))
new_word = First_Replace(word, 'hy', "how")
print(new_word)
```

input : shy

output : 1
show

but with

input : shyer

output : 1

instead of : 1
shower

Comment: @nacho: the code is not working as the OP expected - that is the question.

Comment: Your final `while` loop in `First_Replace` is not incrementing the `i` value.

Comment: as @jsbueno clarified that's the question

Comment: I recommend that you learn how to debug your code. This is a critical skill since we basically never write the code correctly the first time. See [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips to get you started.

Comment: Also any comments regarding the style or any optimizations will be well appreciated. like I noticed in Ino_String() I can make the while loop i <= len(word)-len(part)

Comment: @MattPitkin can you explain more please

Comment: @Code-Apprentice is there a way I can run the code step by step in Pycharm?

Comment: @MohaMed Yes, google "pycharm debugger" and look for a link to the documentation on `jetbrains.com` that explains how to do this.

Comment: As for other suggestions, I recommend that you learn about for loops and slices. I think these in combination can simplify your code.

Comment: For example, you can do `new_word = word[:s] + new_part + word[i:]` to simplify `First_Replace()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually quite a simple fix. The reason you are only getting `1` as output is because the program loops indefinitely here:

```py
while i < len(word):
    new_word += word[i]
```

Looking at intermediate outputs, you can quickly see the word becomes showe, showee, showee, ..., showeeeee...

All you need to do to fix this program is to increment `i`:

```py
while i < len(word):
    new_word += word[i]
    i += 1
```

Also, quite trivially, you can do this to do the same functionality in one line:

```py
word = 'shyer'
match = 'hy'
replace = 'how'
new_word = replace.join(word.split(match))
```

Comment: Oh Can't beleive how I missed such an obvious mistake